# jQuery $.Deferred() with Dynamic Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, promise

I am starting to re-factor some code to use promises and caching to ensure cleaner code.  My Code (See below) has tried to use this new premise and is working with slight success.  The main issue is that the caching mechanism that is uses by default prevents my from being able to "pass" in a dynamic url value without it returning the same cached results every time.  How can i update the code below to use a cache key?

```
"use strict";

var FLEX = window.FLEX|| {};
FLEX.Following = FLEX.Following|| {}; 

FLEX.Following.Process = function () {

var deferred = $.Deferred(),
execute = function (followUrl) {
    $.ajax(
            {
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                    followUrl,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                }
            }
        );
    return deferred;
};
return {
    execute: execute
}

}();

FLEX.Following.Init = function (divName, followUrl) {
FLEX.Following.Process.execute(followUrl).promise().then(

    //success
    function (data) {
        var html = "";
        $.each(data.d.Followed.results,function(index, value){
           html += value.Name + "<br />";
        });

        $(divName).html(html);

    },

    //failure
    function(err) {
        $(divName).html('Failed');
    }   
);             
}
```

I then call the code using the following lines:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        FLEX.Following.Init("#followed-sites", "/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=4)");
        FLEX.Following.Init("#followed-people", "/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=1)");
        FLEX.Following.Init("#followed-documents", "/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=2)");     
    });
```

The resulting output "works" however i get the same results in each div as it appears that every subsequent call jQuery gets the cached version from one of them and therefore each result set is identical.  How can i ensure that i can use the same functions with the different dynamic urls as above and cache them separately.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the root problem is that you create a single `$.Deferred()` and then you try to reuse it for multiple calls to `execute()` and that won't ever work. A deferred is a one-shot trigger.  Once it has been fulfilled or rejected it stays that way and contains the same data forever. If you want a different result on subsequent calls, you have to create a new deferred for each call. So, because you were creating your deferred outside of the `execute()` function, you only ever had one deferred and thus the first result would just stick forever.

The fix here is to use a separate promise/deferred for each call to `execute()`. Since `$.ajax()` already returns a new promise each time you call it - you can use that instead of creating your own `$.Deferred` manually which is an anti-pattern. Let's refactor and solve both issues at once.

Here's your function refactored so solve those issues:

```
var execute = function (followUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
         url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + followUrl,
         method: "GET",
         headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}
    });
};
```

Then, in this line of code:

```
FLEX.Following.Process.execute(followUrl).promise().then(
```

You should remove the `.promise()` because my change above is already returning a promise so this line can just become this:

```
FLEX.Following.Process.execute(followUrl).then(
```

Comment: Thanks for this..Is there anyway to keep the cache and the different urls or is this just an issue for this kind of re-factoring?

Comment: Also refactoring to return as above is not returning the same data object that the previous example was?  is this as design?  how do i get that object back?

Comment: @user257503 - you can remove the `cache: false` if you want.  It has nothing to do with the refactoring.  I thought you were complaining about a problem with caching of your URLS, but now I think the real issue was probably that you only had one deferred for all the URLs and my refactoring fixed that so you can remove the `cache` line if you want.

Comment: @user257503 - you'll have to show me what code you're got now after the refactor because the exact same data should be in the returned promise that you were putting in your `.resolve()`.  You should see the same result of the Ajax call in the `data` variable in this: `FLEX.Following.Process.execute(followUrl).then(function(data) { your code here});`

Comment: @user257503 - to better explain what I think was happening, I've rewritten the explanation in my answer and removed any references to the caching issue because now that I understand your issue better, that wasn't what was really going on.